# Python regular expression split with optional word in pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a string around a particular phrase that may or may not include a particular word. I'm struggling to find the right syntax for this.

Here's the current version of the code:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

text = """Here is a list: Bob talked to Caleb, and Caleb talked to Derek, and Derek talked to Eric, and Eric talked to Fred, and Fred talked to Greg, and Greg talked to Henry, and Henry talked to Isaac, and Isaac talked to Jesse, and Jesse talked to Ken."""

pprint(re.split(r"(a?n?d? ?\w+ talked to)",text))
```

In this example, I want to split on "Bob talked to" or "and Caleb talked to", so the and should be included if it is there or not if it isn't.

This code yields (almost correctly):

```
['Here is a list:',
 ' Bob talked to',
 ' Caleb, ',
 'and Caleb talked to',
 ' Derek, ',
 'and Derek talked to',
 ' Eric, ',
 'and Eric talked to',
 ' Fred, ',
 'and Fred talked to',
 ' Greg, ',
 'and Greg talked to',
 ' Henry, ',
 'and Henry talked to',
 ' Isaac, ',
 'and Isaac talked to',
 ' Jesse, ',
 'and Jesse talked to',
 ' Ken.']
```

The only slight error is that there is a space in front of "Bob", which is being caught because there is a " ?" in the regular expression. So I do not want each of the letters "a?n?d? ?". I would rather have "(and )?"

Unfortunately, these are the results:

```
print(re.split(r"((and )?\w+ talked to)",text))
```

Gives me:

```
['Here is a list: ',
 'Bob talked to',
 None,
 ' Caleb, ',
 'and Caleb talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Derek, ',
 'and Derek talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Eric, ',
 'and Eric talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Fred, ',
 'and Fred talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Greg, ',
 'and Greg talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Henry, ',
 'and Henry talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Isaac, ',
 'and Isaac talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Jesse, ',
 'and Jesse talked to',
 'and ',
 ' Ken.']
```

Here, it is looking for both units separately. I might be able to work with this, but it would be better if it were one unit.

Another option might be:

```
pprint(re.split(r"([and ]?\w+ talked to)",text))
```

Gives:

```
['Here is a list:',
 ' Bob talked to',
 ' Caleb, and',
 ' Caleb talked to',
 ' Derek, and',
 ' Derek talked to',
 ' Eric, and',
 ' Eric talked to',
 ' Fred, and',
 ' Fred talked to',
 ' Greg, and',
 ' Greg talked to',
 ' Henry, and',
 ' Henry talked to',
 ' Isaac, and',
 ' Isaac talked to',
 ' Jesse, and',
 ' Jesse talked to',
 ' Ken.']
```

In this case, the "and " is not being included even though it's available. So how can I make the "and " optional as a unit? In other words, "and " is either in or out, but not in or out in parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
((?:and )?\w+ talked to)
```

The `(?:and )` is a non capturing group, so it matches but isn't captured.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you. Non-capturing group now rings a bell and makes sense in a way that it didn't when I first read about it!